# Angular 4 Aot compile with cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, aot

I try compile my angular4 project with Aot compilation, but show errors

my package.json

```
{
"name": "crm",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.4",
 "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
 "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
 "primeng": "^4.0.3",
 "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
 "typescript": "^2.3.4",
 "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "^1.1.3",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
  "karma": "~1.4.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.1.0",
  "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
  "tslint": "~4.4.2",
  "typescript": "^2.3.4"
 }
}
```

My main.ts file

```
 import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
 import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
 import { environment } from './environments/environment';

  if (environment.production) {
     enableProdMode();
  }
  platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModule);
```

i use this command for compileing :

```
ng build -aot
```

then show`s error

```
ERROR in D:/project_name/src/main.ts (9,42): Argument of type 'typeof AppModule' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModuleFactory<{}>'.
Property 'moduleType' is missing in type 'typeof AppModule'.
```

Jit - compilation work successfully but Aot compilation show error, i can`t find any resources to resolve this problem, please help to resolve this problem

My AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login/login.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
. . . . . .
import { GlobalDataService } from './services/global-data.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ButtonModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    . . . . . .
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [GlobalDataService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: please provide AppModule code.

Comment: I added AppModule - @Avi

Comment: The Angular CLI now automatically builds with AoT enabled if you use the --prod flag.

Maybe u pass the wrong command for build, it's 
ng build --aot 
not 
ng build -aot

Comment: I agree with Ashish, use "platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);" and build in prod mode.

Comment: no I use rightly command @AshishKadam

Comment: I find my mistake @AshishKadam, thank for answer

Answer (score 1):

I find a resolve i write wrong main.ts

```
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModule);
```

Must be

```
platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

AOT Compiler successfully WORK!